# Azure File Sync Svc installed on same server as SQL Server Issues

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, azure, sql-server-2016

I've got Azure File Sync Service installed on the same server as SQL Server 2016.

I'm attributing the issue to the File Sync service because this is the only change made to server after the issues start.

The app logs show the following error [DBNETLIB][ConnectionWrite (send()).] General network error. This happens about once or twice a day

The server is on esxi, with vmxnet3 Ethernet adaptor, running Win 2012 R2

Has any one else had issues?

Comment: `I'm attributing the issue to the File Sync service` - ummm... what issue? You haven't described your actual problem. `The app logs show the following error [DBNETLIB][ConnectionWrite (send()).] General network error. This happens about once or twice a day` - Some context and detail about what this is in relation to would be nice.

Comment: What is the exact issue here? Is it just a warning in the eventlogs (presumably out of nowhere)?

Comment: The issue is that our core app stop working (crashes). To cure the issue simply, a reboot is done. The app uses a mixture of file access and DB access to work. I've had a look in event log for any issues/errors but nothing that can be attributed.  The DBNETLB error is registry in the applications log folder. I am trying to understand if this configuration is causing a problem File Sync Service and SQL Server installed on the same system. As mentioned the issue  has only started since File Sync Services have been installed

Comment: why are you putting file sync on the SQL server?

Comment: The SQL Server is install on Windows 2012 machine